# RxJS Change loading indication message depending on request time

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to implement loading indication (spinner and the message below) using RxJS.

- From 0 to 30sec the message would be 'Your request is being processed...'
- after 30sec - the message would be 'Your request is being processed..., it usually takes less then minute'.

If data arrives successfully earlier than 30 seconds, the loader with message would disappear.

I am implementing this in Angular project.
The code below is kind of draft version, and it doesn't work as expected, because api data waits for timer to be completed

```
  public initializeDashboard() {
    const timerMessage$ = timer(30000, 1000).pipe(take(1));
    const dashboard$: Array<any> = this.headerService.getItems();

    this.progressMessage = 'Your request is being processed...';
    merge(timerMessage$, dashboard$).pipe(
      tap((item) => {
        if (isNumber(item)) {
          this.progressMessage = 'Usually it takes less then a minute';
        }
      }),
      filter(item => isArray(item)))
      .subscribe(
        (responseData) => {
            this.progressMessage = '';
             this.responseData = responseData,
          }
      );
  }
```

Comment: So how is `dashboard$` related to the functionality you want when it's in the same chain?

Comment: dashboard$ is the data observable that I want to retrieve from API, but it may take from 10 to 40 sec to get response

Comment: `combineLatest` it with `timer`. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: So you want to keep the message visible until `dashboard$` emits.

Comment: I want to make it dynamic. If reponse takes less then 30 sec then it would be msg1, and from 31sec and till response from server - msg2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that I'll merge two chains where the first one will only make a side-effect and update the message while the second one is the one that using `take(1)` can complete the chain. This is necessary because you obviously want to cancel the timer when 
`dashboard$` emits.

I think there's another variant without `ignoreElements()` but that would require also `takeUntil()` and `share()` and making two separate subscriptions so this is I think the easier one.

```
public initializeDashboard() {
  const dashboard$: Array<any> = this.headerService.getItems();
  const timerMessage$ = timer(30 * 1000) // This will emit just once after 30s
    .pipe(
      tap(() => this.progressMessage += 'Usually it takes less then a minute'),
      ignoreElements(), // all emission will be ignored so they won't reach `take(1)` and complete the chain
    ); 

  this.progressMessage = 'Your request is being processed...';

  merge(timerMessage$, dashboard$)
    .pipe(
      take(1), // This is required so when `dashboard$` emits it will unsubscribe from `timerMessage$` automatically
    )
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
      this.progressMessage = '';
      this.responseData = responseData,
    });
}
```